# Assign a value to a input field via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of an input field with jquery.

I generate the target id as follows:

```
var target_id = the_clicked_button.replace('_btn','');

var myValue = "sample";
```

I want to assign the value of myValue to target_id. Here's what I've tried out.

```
("#($( "target_id" ).val();)").val(myValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#' + target_id).val(myValue);
//    ^ String Concatenation
```